# .htaccess: Rewrite GET as semantic URL and emulate folder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to rewrite this:

- mysite.com/**albums** > mysite.com/**albums.php**
- mysite.com/**albums/** > mysite.com/**albums.php**
- mysite.com/**albums/foo** or **/albums/foo/** > mysite.com/**albums/foo.html** *(check next line)*
- mysite.com/**albums/foo.html** > mysite.com/**albums.php?album=foo**
- mysite.com/**albums/foo/bar** or **/albums/foo/bar/** > mysite.com/**albums/foo/bar.html** *(check next line)*
- mysite.com/**albums/foo/bar.html** > mysite.com/**albums.php?album=foo&photo=bar**

The current `.htaccess` so far:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule /albums/(.*)/(.*)/ albums.php?album=$1&photo=$2
RewriteRule albums/(.*)/(.*) albums.php?album=$1&photo=$2
RewriteRule /albums/(.*)/ albums.php?album=$1
RewriteRule albums/(.*) albums.php?album=$1
RewriteRule /albums/ albums.php
```

But is a mess with errors, how can this work well?

**NOTE**: **This must work just with `/albums.php`, not with other `.php` files like `/index.php`, `/contact.php`, etc.**

Comment: Not clear what you mean by `mysite.com/albums/foo > mysite.com/foo.html`. Does `/foo.html` exist?

Comment: @anubhava Oh sorry, two mistakes when typed, corrected.

Comment: RewriteRule ^(albums)/(.*)/(.*)$ albums.php?album=$2&photo=$3 you forgot to add 'start' and 'end' seperators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try these rules in your root .htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^albums/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)(?:\.html|/)?$ albums.php?album=$1&photo=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^albums/([\w-]+)(?:\.html|/)?$ albums.php?album=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^albums(?:\.html|/)?$ albums.php [L,NC]
```